# Using Filesort - Can't avoid it, even using index

Tags: mysql, filesort

I have a table with 40,000,000 rows, and I'm trying to optimize my query, because takes too long. 
First, this is my table: 
CREATE TABLE `resume` ( 
  `yearMonth` char(6) DEFAULT NULL, 
  `type` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `agen_o` char(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tar` char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cve_ent` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cve_mun` char(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cve_reg` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_ope` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ope_tip` char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ope_cve` char(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cob_u` int(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tot_imp` bigint(15) DEFAULT NULL,
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

This is my query: 
SELECT m.name_ope AS cve, 
SUBSTRING(r.yearMonth,5,2) AS period, 
COUNT(DISTINCT(CONCAT(r.agen_ope,r.cve_ope))) AS num, 
SUM(CASE WHEN r.type='A' THEN r.cob_u ELSE 0 END) AS tot_u, 
FROM resume r, media m 
WHERE CONCAT(r.id_ope,SUBSTRING(r.ope_cve,3,1))=m.ope_cve AND  
r.type IN ('C','D','E') AND 
SUBSTRING(r.yearMonth,1,4)='2012' AND 
r.id_ope='X' AND 
SUBSTRING(r.ope_cve,1,2) IN (SELECT cve_med FROM catNac WHERE numero='0')
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(r.yearMonth,5,2),SUBSTRING(r.ope_cve,3,1) 
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(r.yearMonth,5,2),SUBSTRING(r.ope_cve,3,1)

So, I added an index with these fields: id_ope, yearMonth, agen_o, because I have other's queries that have this fields in WHERE, with this order 
 
Now my explain output:
1   PRIMARY r   ref indice  indice  2   const   14774607    Using where; Using filesort

So i added another index with yearMonth, ope_cve, but I still have "using filesort". How can I optimize this? 
Thanks

Comment: MySQL will not be able to use indexes because you're using functions (In this case, SUBSTRING).

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought that could be the reason

Comment: Looking at the field YearMonth, What is the format of the content? Is it something like 201206 for june 2012?

Comment: That's right. It's 201201, 201202, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without modifying your table structure, if you have an index on yearMonth, you can try this:

```
SELECT m.name_ope AS cve,
SUBSTRING(r.yearMonth,5,2) AS period,
COUNT(DISTINCT(CONCAT(r.agen_ope,r.cve_ope))) AS num,
SUM(CASE WHEN r.type='A' THEN r.cob_u ELSE 0 END) AS tot_u,
FROM resume r, media m
WHERE CONCAT(r.id_ope,SUBSTRING(r.ope_cve,3,1))=m.ope_cve AND
r.type IN ('C','D','E') AND
r.yearMonth LIKE '2012%' AND
r.id_ope='X' AND
SUBSTRING(r.ope_cve,1,2) IN (SELECT cve_med FROM catNac WHERE numero='0')
GROUP BY r.yearMonth,SUBSTRING(r.ope_cve,3,1)
```

The changes:

- Using `r.yearMonth LIKE '2012%'` should allow an index to be used for that part of your where clause.
- Since you're already filtering out every year but 2012, you can group by `GROUP BY r.yearMonth` alone.
- The `ORDER BY` clause is not needed since MySQL sorts on `GROUP BY`, unless you include `ORDER BY NULL`

Comment: Thank you for your observations...So, I need to do another index just for yearMonth? And also, I need to order or group, first for SUBSTRING(r.yearMonth, 5, 2), which is the month. Grouping just by y.yearMonth, I'll have the results grouped by year, not by month, right?

Comment: Grouping by just yearmonth, you'll have the result grouped by year, then month. But since you're already filtering by year in your where clause, it's going to be grouped by 201201, 201202... and so on, so it should have the same result. The only fields that your query could benefit from indexing are `id_ope`, `yearMonth` and `type`. Your current index on `id_ope` and `yearMonth` should help this specific query.

Comment: You're right, I don't know who I didn't notice that... Thanks for your help. One last question, when I do my queries, my CPU comes to 100%-200%, but my memory almost  don't change, like if MySQL as using CPU instead Memory... Do you know what can be the reason?

Comment: The amount memory that MySQL will use is usually pretty stable, depending on your configuration. In this case, it's probably trying to sort/filter all the data it has in memory, but I'm mostly guessing here.

Comment: Thank you. I have to remove my index, because my queries takes more time, and also creates tmp tables, and without index don't create tmp tables